# Golang docker container exiting inmediately after it starts

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose

My container exits and I don't know why, probably because I don't know enough Go and of course Docker.

Here is my `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml`.

The reason of that network name is because this `docker-compose` file is being extended by another at a parent folder together with other apps. Also the version 2.

The `go get./` and `go buid` I took it from Go official image at dockerhub, and the `go mod download` and `go run cmd/server/main.go` are commands the app needs to run.

```
FROM golang:1.13

RUN mkdir /prework_ms

COPY . /prework_ms

WORKDIR /prework_ms

RUN cd /prework_ms \
    go get ./ \
    go build \
    go mod download \
    go run cmd/server/main.go

EXPOSE 8080
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "2"
services:
    go:
        build: .
        volumes:
            - .:/prework_ms
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        networks:
            - appnet
    mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7.25
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        volumes:
            - ./sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
        networks:
            - appnet
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: prework
            MYSQL_DATABASE: prework
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command that starts the service is declared using the Dockerfile [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) instruction. Also, the `RUN` commands should be separated using shell's `&&`:

```
FROM golang:1.13

RUN mkdir /prework_ms   
COPY . /prework_ms   
WORKDIR /prework_ms   
RUN go get ./ && go build && go mod download
EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["go", "run", "cmd/server/main.go"]
```

Comment: @MarcosDiPaolo how do you run it, and what does it show?

Comment: sorry @bereal, my bad. Now i get another error, related with the `RUN` commands: `go get .: path /prework_ms is not a package in module rooted at /prework_ms`

Comment: @MarcosDiPaolo Try `go get ...` instead.

Comment: thanks alot @bereal, even if now i get another error, i believe it's outside this question's scope

Comment: I get a dependencies error, but if i remove the `go get` and `go build` everything works great, but again the container quits

Comment: @MarcosDiPaolo there must be something in the container logs, I guess, the service just fails to start without the dependencies.